Cheeger-Gromov limit of scalings of a noncompact Riemannian manifold
I am interested in the Cheeger-Gromov compactness theorem for sequences of Riemannian manifolds, and I stumbled across a question about smooth pointed Cheeger-Gromov convergence that I’m having trouble answering. If $(M^n,g)$ is a compact Riemannian manifold, $p_j$ is a sequence of points in $M$, and $r_j$ is a sequence of positive real numbers diverging to infinity, one can show that any pointed $C^{\infty}$ Cheeger-Gromov limit of the scalings $(M,r_j^2g,p_j)$ must be pointed-isometric to Euclidean $n$-space. I’m curious whether one can find an example of a complete noncompact Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, with $p_j$ and $r_j$ as before, such that $(M,r_j^2g,p_j)$ converges in the pointed $C^{\infty}$ Cheeger-Gromov sense to a non-Euclidean pointed $n$-manifold.
I’ve tried to find examples in $2$ dimensions working with the hyperbolic plane or other non-Euclidean planes with metrics $dx^2+h(x)^2dy^2$ for some smooth positive function $h(x)$, but every example I’ve found either doesn’t converge at all, doesn’t converge to a Riemannian metric (i.e. it degenerates in the limit), or starts with an incomplete noncompact manifold.

Let $M$ be a manifold for which there exists a sequence of points $p_k$ such that in the geodesic ball $B(p,r_k^{-1})$, the metric has constant nonzero sectional curvature $r_k^{-2}$.

Interesting. Do you mean to say that the metric $g$ has constant nonzero sectional curvature $r_k^2$ in each geodesic ball? If this is true, then in the new scaled metric $r_k^2g$, the curvature is constant equal to $1$ in each ball since sectional curvature scales inversely to the metric. If this is the case, the example I have in mind involves the connect sum of $S^2$’s, one for each positive integer $k$, yielding a topological $\mathbb{R}^2$, where the $k$th copy has radius $1/k$. Then choose a point $p_k$ in each copy (sufficiently far away from the join regions).

Of course, to make this idea fully rigorous, we have to multiply each metric on the sphere copies by a smooth cutoff function that interpolates between the metrics of different radii over a small enough region. The picture I have in mind is a sort of “infinite Christmas tree,” sans star, with each new row of branches being a sphere of radius $1/k$. It should converge to a pointed $\mathbb{R}^2$ equipped with a metric of constant positive curvature $1$. Many thanks for your help!

Take the quotient $M$ of the hyperbolic (upper half) plane by the cyclic group generated by the translation $z\mapsto z+1$. Take points $p_k\in M$ which are projections of $k\sqrt{-1}$. Use $r_k=\sqrt{k}$. Then the Gromov-Hausdorff limit will be isometric to $\mathbb R$.  If one takes $r_k=k$, the limit will be a flat cylinder. As Deane says, one can also get manifolds of nonzero curvature as limits.

Very nifty example! Thank you! I’m not sure why I didn’t think of this initially. In this case, the sequence of diffeomorphisms you use to prove smooth Cheeger-Gromov convergence is given by $\phi_k(\theta,t)=(\theta,ke^{\frac{t}{k}})$ for $(\theta,t)\in S^1\times\mathbb{R}$.
